# Compaq Presario Laptop Monitor Problems

Tags: display, lcd, laptop-repair

I am attaching a few pics of my laptop monitor now . Can you please tell me if this is a hardware error which can be rectified by replacing the monitor ?
How this happened - I accidently hit my leg on the laptop and jammed it against the wall and ever since the monitor is like this .I plan to replace the Monitor by buying a spare parts laptop that sells in ebay .  I wonder if this is a LCD HARDWARE problem or problem with the cable that goes to the monitor . THE OS works fine in the computer.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I found that the product is LTN140W-l01 Monitor made by samsung . 
Does anyone know if I can buy a competitor prodct like mentioned here : 



Quanta: QD14WL01 (LK01), QD14WL01 (LK11), QD14WL01 Rev.01, QD14WL01 Rev.02, QD14WL01 Rev.04

Samsung: LTN140W, LTN140W1-L01, LTN140W1-L01-1, LTN140W1-L01-AG, LTN140W1-L02


Also can I use any other series of LAPTOPS ( maybe cheaper ones ) like say a 12 inch or 15 inch ones ? Would the jacks be compatible ?

Answer (score 0):

That is a cracked LCD panel, it will need to be replaced.

[Here's some more pictures of cracked LCDs from Google Images](http://images.google.ca/images?hl=en&source=hp&q=cracked+LCD&gbv=2&aq=f&aqi=g3&aql=&oq=) for comparison. :)

Comment: Thank you very much for that info .Would I have to replace the to replace the monitor as a whole ? Would it be a nice idea to buy one of those laptop for spare parts and replace it . How do I go about it

Comment: You could replace the whole lid, but really it appears you've only broken the LCD panel itself, and changing the entire lid is often the same amount of work as swapping the internal LCD panel alone. You'll want to get an EXACT spare, and then find some disassembly instructions (which, depending on the make/model, are usually pretty easy to find via a search engine). Oh and ensure you've got some jewelers' screwdrivers. :)