# Can we connect a laptop to an external normal monitor?

Tags: laptop, lcd, display

Can we connect a LAPTOP to an external monitor ?
Here is my problem -> 
[Compaq Presario Laptop Monitor Problems](https://superuser.com/questions/120269/compaq-presario-laptop-monitor-problems)

I want to buy a external monitor but the problem is that they come at huge cost and probably getting a new laptop or netbook seems wiser. So I am looking for cheap solutions .

Comment: External monitors are quite cheap and keep getting cheaper.  You can find a 19" LCD for under a 100 in the states now.  Would be cheaper than replacing the laptop, but not nearly as portable.

Answer (score 3):

You can certainly connect a laptop to an external graphical output, be it CRT monitor, LCD monitor or projector, as long as the laptop has a VGA output (which it should). This is usually located on the back edge of the laptop (or occasionally the side).

There will be a key combination - often Fn+F5 to switch between the various modes. You might need to do this every time you reboot as diverting (or replicating) the output is a Windows level action.

Comment: My current LCD is botched up so I dont need Fn+F5 options as of now .
Where is the VGA Output of the Laptop ? 
I removed the Bezel and took out the LCD Panel . It has 2 wires going to the LCD Panel . One is a paralell port and the the other looks like Power .

Comment: VGA output will be on the side or back of the laptop. You definitely do **NOT** need to take the laptop apart to used the output!

Comment: @Chris_K - cheers, I should have pointed that out!

Comment: Thanks , dont worry I didnt do this after you said , I did the before itself ! But very useful info .

Comment: I have a female VGA Port on my Laptop . So I should get a LCD Screen and then a cable with male VGA pin , is that correct ?
Also I want to know how can I make this dedicated and not optional like Fn+F5

Comment: @Nishant - yes that's the port and a normal VGA cable will fit. You might be able make it dedicated, but a quick search for "compaq presario external monitor" showed up a couple of forums where people were asking the same question and the answer seemed to be that you couldn't. However, a more dedicated search might reveal an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the laptop has a VGA, HDMI or DVI port you definitely can connect an external monitor.

In fact, even if it doesn't have any video ports (unlikely) you could even look into a USB video adapter. But that may not be nearly as cost effective.